# Using regex to insert text BEFORE a line containing something (Notepad++)?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have several lines like this:

```
Apples
__________
B
C

Bananas
___________
D
E

Carrots
____________
F 
G
```

I would like to make it so that Apples, bananas, and carrots are each their own separate heading in html.  So I would like to do a regex search for 3 consecutive underscores or more and then insert html heading tags in the line preceding it.  Can someone tell me how to do this with Notepad++ regex search and replace?

Answer (score 2):

Search for

```
(^|\n)(.*)([\n\r]+)(_{3,})([\n\r]|$)
```

and replace it with

```
$1<h1>$2</h1>$5
```

---

[image]

Comment: I've tried both of the previous suggestions in regex and extended, and it cannot find relevant text.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Ωmega: Maybe OP's having a problem with line breaks and carriage returns. But apart from that your expression should be fine. +1 **P.S.** *you should change your username because it's second to impossible to refer to you. It may seem fancy but it would be better if it started with a standard letter*

Comment: If it's a problem with line breaks and carriage returns, how do I fix that?  I think that has screwed me up once before.

Comment: @user964946 - Use `(^|\n)(.*)([\n\r]+)(\s*_{3,})([\n\r]|$)`. You have there probably some extra spaces.

Comment: Thank you everyone for their input!  I guess what's wrong is on my end :/  I'll keep at it